# Python: How to convert list of lists into data frame?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I currently have a lists of lists which I have converted to a dataframe as you can see in the screenshot. I would like to break up each list into separate columns. Since each list has 5 entries, the resulting dataframe would be 10 columns by 720 rows. Does anyone know how to efficiently do this? I can create a bunch of for loops, but it is not efficient in my eyes. Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are given two 720 by 5 lists `a` and `b` as in columns `0` and `1` respectively (here mocked by random values for demonstration), you could e.g. create two separate `pd.DataFrame`s first and then merge them using `pd.concat`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((720, 5)).tolist()
b = np.random.random((720, 5)).tolist()

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a), pd.DataFrame(b)], axis=1)
print(df.shape)
```

prints

```
(720, 10)
```